# Check if a loaded webpage contains certain text?

Tags: vb.net, html

Using VB.Net, how would I go about checking if a loaded page in a Web Browser object contains a certain line of text? Sorry if theres an obvious answer for this, I'm used to programming in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Browser object has a DocumentText property that allows you to get or set the HTML contents.  You can search the HTML for the text.

See more on the WebBrowser class:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, that worked perfectly.  I had that initially but after consulting msdn, I got confused. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Happy to help.  Don't forget to upvote and mark this answer correct if appropriate.